# Не получается подключить библиотеку c++ CMake

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, clion, library

Мне нужна библиотека glfw. Я работаю в clion, а он вроде не умеет подключать библиотеки сам, так что нужно вручную писать файлы cmake. Я ни разу с ним не работал. Посмотрел в интернете как это делается, и как не странно, ничего не получается. Что только я не пробовал - всегда ошибка. На скриншоте снизу видно структуру проекта, CMakeLists.txt файл и консоль cmake с ошибками. Что я делаю не так? Что нужно исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код текстом кому нужно

```
project(VoxelEngine)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(VoxelEngine main.cpp)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

set(GLFW_DIR "../Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64")

include_directories( "${GLFW_DIR}/include")

find_library(glfw NAMES glfw3 PATHS "${GLFW_DIR}/lib-vc2017" REQUIRED)


target_link_libraries( VoxelEngine ${glfw} opengl32)
```

Что касается CLion, мне очень нравятся IDE от JetBrains, как то не хочется переходить на что-либо другое. Но пока что проблем с местным CMake не возникает, вроде всё линкуется. Но если трудности возникнут, придётся поменять IDE

Ошибки сборки:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to:                             
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/src/cmake-build-debug
Scanning dependencies of target VoxelEngine
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/VoxelEngine.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable VoxelEngine.exe
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib-        
vc2019/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj):(.text$mn+0x73): undefined     
reference to `__imp___stdio_common_vsprintf'
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib-    
vc2019/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj):(.text$mn+0x327): undefined     
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib-    
vc2019/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj): 
(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInputError]+0xc): undefined reference to         
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib-    
vc2019/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x196):     
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib- 
vc2019/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x82):     
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib-    
vc2019/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x91): 
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib- 
vc2019/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x9b):     
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
<.....>
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib- 
vc2019/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/egl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x534):     
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib- 
vc2019/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x1cd): 
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib- 
vc2019/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj): 
(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInitOSMesa]+0xc): undefined reference to 
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib- 
vc2019/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj): 
(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwCreateContextOSMesa]+0x10): undefined reference to 
`__GSHandlerCheck'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\VoxelEngine.dir\build.make:106:     
VoxelEngine.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94:     
CMakeFiles/VoxelEngine.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:101: 
CMakeFiles/VoxelEngine.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:136: VoxelEngine] Error 2
```

ошибки сборки, если удалить lib-vc2019:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build 
 C:\Users\Maksim\CLionProjects\VoxelEngine\src\cmake-build-debug --target 
VoxelEngine -- -j 9
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** No rule to make target     
'C:/Users/Maksim/CLionProjects/VoxelEngine/Libraries/glfw-    
3.3.4.bin.WIN64/lib-vc2019/glfw3.lib', needed by 'VoxelEngine.exe'.  Stop.
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94:     
CMakeFiles/VoxelEngine.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:101:     
CMakeFiles/VoxelEngine.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:136: VoxelEngine] Error 2
```

Comment: Читали https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html

Comment: Код нужно показывать текстом. Скриншот Вашего CLion никому не интересен.

Comment: @KoVadim прочитал. Написал так как показывают в статье. Получившийся код поменял в вопросе. Всё равно не запускается

Comment: а Вас не смущает, что написано add_subdirectory, а Вы ей файл подсовываете, ещё и с странными двойными слешами? Перечитайте внимательно то, что там написано.

Comment: @KoVadim пробовал давать ей папку Lib или Includes/GLFW. Ошибка такая: add_subdirectory not given a binary directory but the given source
directory. Пожалуйста, напишите конкретно что мне нужно делать. В библиотеке, которую я скачал нет .cpp файлов, только заголовочные и .lib. Я задаю функции add_subdirectory папку, что ей теперь не нравится? Что вообще делать с этими .lib .h файлами? Как из них получить библиотеку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел и понял, что в стандартной поставке под винду нет cmake файла для glfw. Пришлось набросать самому. В нем комментарии, так что справитесь - нужно только в одном месте поправить

```
project(VoxelEngine)
# не нужно использовать старую версию, хотя бы 3
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(VoxelEngine main.cpp)

# нам нужен OpenGL.
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

# это каталог, в который Вы распаковали архив
# его Вы задаете сами! Подозреваю, что возможно, Вам нужно будет просто 
# "./" или что то подобное - у Вас ведь оно прям в папку с проектом распаковано
set(GLFW_DIR "../libs/glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64")

# в нем должна быть папка  include, мы ее добавим
include_directories( "${GLFW_DIR}/include")

# а эта строка поищет собственно lib файл. Возможно, Вам нужно будет тут уточнить путь/имя.
# В каталоге должен быть файл glfw3.lib или что то подобное - glfw3.a
# переменная glfw теперь хранит путь к этому файлу
find_library(glfw NAMES glfw3 PATHS "${GLFW_DIR}/lib-vc2019" REQUIRED)


target_link_libraries( VoxelEngine ${glfw} opengl32)
```

И забудьте на время о clion - он несет с собой какую то странную версию cmake, с ней бывают непонятности. Плюс он мешает осваивать вначале.

Если не будет линковаться - возможно, в каталоге Libs лежат не подходящие файлы. Тут уже нужно уточнять компилятор и качать по нему.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11501/281034

Comment: Для удобства я распаковал файлы библиотеки в отдельную папку Libraries, а Lib и Includes удалил за ненадобностью. Написал Ваш код в CMakeLists.txt, в main.cpp подключил #include "../Libraries/glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64/Include/GLFW/glfw3.h",и теперь всё собирается и работает, но только до того момента как я использую какую-нибудь функцию glfw. В main я вызываю glfwInit(); и получаю множество ошибок при сборке (напишу их в тексте вопроса), предполагаю, что это из за отсутствия библиотеки glew. Если это так, её подключать аналогично с glfw? В тот же CMakeLists?

Comment: Мой cmake написан так, что бы #include не нужно было исправлять. Только один путь в cmake. А ошибки скорее всего линковки. Нужен ли glew я не знаю, но если Вам нужен, то можно его аккуратно добавить

Comment: Посмотрел ошибки линковки. Это проблема с тем, что lib файл от другого компилятора. Скорее всего CLion использует mingw  или что то подобное, а либы от студии

Comment: Да, я ставил ему mingv. Но clion умеет работать с разными компиляторами, и, как пишут JetBrains, в том числе и с компилятором visual studio. Если я установлю студию и поставлю её компилятор для clion, решит ли это проблему? Какой версии нужно ставить студию для c++17? И вообще, лучший ли вариант использовать именно 17ую версию компилятора? Какие пакеты нужно выбирать при установке студии?

Comment: У вас проблема не в компиляторе, а в том что lib файлы положили не от того компилятора. В скачано архиве должна быть папка lib-mingw-w64 вместо lib-vc2019 нужна ( поправьте в cmake).

Comment: попробовал подключать mingw-w64. Ошибки остались те же, но если удалить папку для vs2019, то он станет ругаться, как я понял, на отсутствие этой папки (содержимое консоли добавил в текст вопроса). Зачем clion ищет библиотеку для vs2019?

Comment: я не знаю, что точно происходит на Вашей машине. Но возможно, нужно удалить содержимое папки со сборкой (сделать чистую сборку). И конечно убедится, что в CMakeLists.txt нет упоминания vs2019

Comment: Создал проект заново и подключил библиотеку. Сейчас всё работает. Огромное спасибо за помощь